# Javascript, check array and nodes surrounding

Tags: javascript, arrays

Ello Chaps and Chapesses!

I have a Javascript array like this:

```
var tinkerArray = [
  [0,0,0],
  [0,1,0],
  [0,0,0]
];
```

My question is, how can I check the array nodes *surrounding* each node...

e.g. starting at `[0,0]`, check `[0,1]` and `[1,0]` etc etc

Thanks!

**edit:** if possible I would like a scalable solution whereby if the array was 7x7 - the algorithm would still work... :/

Comment: What exactly do you want to "check"? If you just want to access the adjacent elements given `i,j`, then access `i-1, j`, `i,j-1`, `i,j+1`, `i+1, j` and ensure that the indicies are valid.

Comment: Is there no better way to do this? If my array changes size - this won't work :(

Comment: oh, im being stupid, it will work! Apologies

Comment: It will work just fine even if your array changes. But like Felix said  you should take care of the edge cases also.

Comment: Given a 'row' of `x` values, are all rows then guaranteed to have `x` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

```
function getSurrounding(arr, i, j) {
  var m, n, result = [];
  for (m = i - 1; m <= i + 1; m++) {
    if (m in arr) {
      for (n = j - 1; n <= j + 1; n++) {
         if (n in arr[m] && !(m == i && n == j)) {
            result.push(arr[m][n]);
         }
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: This also gets the diagonal elements... maybe this is desired, I just wanted to point it out. (loops look so much nicer ;))

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to access the adjacent elements given `i,j`, then access `i-1, j`, `i,j-1`, `i,j+1`, `i+1, j` and ensure that the indicies are valid.

It's not very pretty, but it works (it assumes `i` and `j` are always valid indicies):

```
function neighbours(arr, i, j) {
    var n = [];
    if((i-1) in arr) {
        n.push(arr[i-1][j]);
    }
    if((j-1) in arr) {
        n.push(arr[i][j-1]);
    }
    if((j+1) in arr) {
        n.push(arr[i][j+1]);
    }
    if((i+1) in arr) {
        n.push(arr[i+1][j]);
    }
    return n;
}
```

This returns a new array containing the neighbours. Of course instead of returning them you can do whatever you want ;)